# CocoaPods won't install on device?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, ipa, enterprise-distribution

So I recently started using `CocoaPods` and I've gotten a few installed and running without any problems. It works perfectly in the simulator, and if I compile the app to a device through xcode it works fine as well. But when I export the app as an `.IPA` and install the app on a device my app crashes. The device log states that a library couldn't be loaded. I tried removing the library it could not load, and it proceeded by not being able to load the next library so it seems that the `.IPA` does not include the `CocoaPods` at all. I would provide you with my settings in the project file but I don't even know where to start looking or what info to provide you with since I'm very new to `CocoaPods`.

Here is the error message:

```
Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded: @rpath/Charts.framework/Charts
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/50931ADA-7E77-42C4-BFKA-0EB4A71BCF63/myApp.app/MyApp
  Reason: no suitable image found.
```

Too clarify: It all works fine **except** when I export the app as an `.IPA`, so I believe the project hierarchy is correct and the pods are installed correctly. I would bet that there is some sort of project setting that prevents it from being exported?

Edit #1: It works when I export the `.IPA` without using an Enterprise account, so the issue is somehow connected to the Enterprise account. I read somewhere that the new Cocoa Touch Framework was a bit buggy and couldn't be used with the Enterprise deployment, is CocoaPods using Cocoa Touch Framework? Anyone else have any other suggestions?

Comment: How are you exporting the .ipa? It sounds like you might be exporting only your main project while the pods project should be part of your build as well.

Comment: @donnywals through Enterprise account. So I archive->Export->Save for Enterprise Deployment. I then install the app through Window->Devices. Do I need to supply the .pList file somehow or is this only needed when installing app through URL?